# Exporting jar with JRE 8, but classes are still with java 7

Tags: eclipse, jar, java-8, export

I changed the Java Compiler in my eclipse workspace to 1.8 and marked the JRE 1.8 as my default.
This change took affect over all java projects in my workspace (I can see that the JRE System Library is pointing to 1.8).

Now I want to generate new jars from these projects with Java 8, but when checking classes version it still points to Java SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex) !
I made sure by opening classes on hex editor and checking the 6,7 bytes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

[image]

or by running this command:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin>javap -verbose < myclass >.class | findstr major

major version: 51

example of one project:

[image]

Comment: You used Eclipse and not Maven or Gradle to create these JARs, right? Please show _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_ of one of the Java projects from which you created a JAR.

Comment: Look at the 'Generated .class file compatibilty' settings in Preferences > Java > Compiler. For individual projects also check the 'Java Compiler' page in the project properties.

Comment: updated with one project properties example

Comment: When project specific settings are not enabled, it is the settings in `Preferences > Java > Compiler` that are used - show us that.

Comment: enabling it didn't help as well !

Comment: I removed java 7 at all from my machine and still... how come!

Comment: When I switched from Oracle Java JRE to IBM Java JRE it worked!!!